# async from dynamically generated array of functions nodeJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

So im working on a nodejs task that runs update tasks from cli

a snippet of my code

```
var
  npm,
  grunt,
  async,
  path,
  which,
  color,
  isRoot,
  progressBar,
  EventEmitter,
  exec,
  utils,
  format;

function loadDependencies() {
  npm = require('npm');
  grunt = require('grunt');
  async = require('async');
  path = require('path');
  which = require('which');
  color = require('cli-color');
  isRoot = require('is-root');
  progressBar = require('progress');
  EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
  exec = require('child_process').exec;
  utils = require('../utils');
  format = require('util').format
}

// Expose my module
module.exports = update;

function update(args, options, callback, ee){
  //Load all my deps 
  loadDeps();
  // Create my array
  var taskCollection = [];
  // Convert the update object with its functions into an array
  for(var tasks in update){
      taskCollection.push('update.' + tasks);
  }
```

**After playing around I decided to try adding the following array here **

```
taskCollection = [update.one, update.two];
```

**And it ran the tasks as it should so I can now only assume its how im making my array**

```
  //And this is were im stuck *
  async.series(taskCollection,
    function(err,result){
    console.log(error);
    console.log(result);
  });

}

update.one = function(callback){
    callback(null, 'Update One Complete);
}

update.two = function(callback){
    callback(null, 'Update Two Complete);
}
```

Now the idea is that the list of tasks for async to run is automatically populated from my update object, meaning that anything like this

```
update.bower = function(){}
update.grunt = function(){}
```

will be run by async but other tasks like

```
var getVersion = function(){}
```

Wont the problem comes when I want to run async on the array of tasks Ive created I keep getting the error task() is not a function

Im trying to use

```
async.series(taskCollection, finish);
```

and some sort of variation of

```
async.each(taskCollection);
```

The ultimate goal will be that a progress bar will be added and so on the callback for each function will call progress.tick() with the number of ticks being automatically counted from the list of tasks

Whats the best way forward?
which async (NodeJs Version) task is best series because i want them in order each as they are an array of functions ?

Thanks in advance banging my head against the wall

Updated!!

The Error is generated from async.js:718 and says

```
task(_restParam(function (err,args))) {
^
TypeError: task is not a function
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to be declaring a function named `task` or passing in something with a function with that name. Where exactly does the code break?

Comment: In the code above were I have put and this is were i get stuck I would make my call to async series so 'async.series(taskCollection, finish);' finish being the function that gets errors/results/callbacks ive checked the array and i get ['update.one, update.two'] if i console.log(taskCollection) meaning that async should run update.one and so on

Comment: I don't understand you. Can you add a stack trace to your question?

Comment: Updated with more code and the error im getting

Answer (score 0):

I was passing async an array of strings rather than objects.

Consider the following:

```
console.log(update);
// And you get
{[Function: update] one: [Function], two [Function]}
```

So in my above code

```
// Translation - For all the keys in the update object
for(var tasks in update){
  // push that key as a string :(
  taskCollection.push('update.' + tasks);
 }
```

Update the for to the following:

```
for (var obj in tasks){
    taskCount.push(obj);
    taskCollection.push(tasks[obj]);
}
```

and now taskCount will produce an array of the function names
and taskCollection will work when passed to async :)

Comment: Am also facing same issue. can you please elaborate this answer with some values.

Comment: This question is 2 years old, I remember the issue I had but now my knowledge is much greater and with es6 I can see multiple ways to solve multiple variations my above code could have caused. For example async.series takes an array or object meaning functions could have been declared using the following: `async.series([()=>{//First Function}, ()=>{//Second Function}], callbackFunciton(allErr,allResults){}) There is also the fact that the object that I was trying to fun the series on was malformed. I will try and update this post with an answer